# How to change fronend URL in Keycloak behind NGINX ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, nginx-ingress

There are many questions like this I can find in the internet but none of the solutions provided worked.

I am using `jboss/keycloak:14.0.0` docker image. The following properties are set in my `ConfigMap`:

```
KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL: /mycontext/access-management
PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
```

Please note that, change the `KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL` to an absolute URL like this `https://mycompany.com/mycontext/access-managemen` makes no difference.

Now the ingress has been defined as below:

```
Path: /mycontext/access-management(/|$)(.*)
Rewrite To: /$2
Annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "False"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header X-Request-ID $request_id;
      proxy_set_header X-Trace-ID $request_id;
      gzip off;
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "180"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "180"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "180"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      add_header X-Request-ID $request_id;
      add_header X-Trace-ID $request_id;
    nginx.org/redirect-to-https: "True"
```

What happens is very strange. See below it shows you where it takes me when I hit a URL:

```
Go to [server]/mycontext/access-management =takes you to=> [server]/auth
Go to [server]/mycontext/access-management/auth =takes you to=> [server]/mycontext/access-management/auth (works fine)
```

As you can see the second link works fine and you can see the Keycloak Welcome page with a number of links in it. One of the links is `Administration Console` that is broken. If you hover your mouse the link is `[server]/mycontext/access-management/admin` instead of `[server]/mycontext/access-management/auth/admin` (comparing it with my local Keycloak server). Now if we ignore the link and put the right path in the address bar as `[server]/mycontext/access-management/auth/admin` another strange thing happens and that changes the URL to `[server]/auth/mycontext/access-management/admin/master/console/`.

I really don't understand what is happening here. Setting `KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL` on my local also breaks the links.

I have tried to change the `rewrite` annotation of the ingress to `/mycontext/access-management/$2` but this configuration doesn't work at all.

In the Keycloak documentation [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#_hostname) it talks about a property named `adminUrl`, however, setting `-DadminUrl` or `-Dkeycloak.adminUrl` seems to be ignored completely by the docker image when using `JAVA_OPTS_APPEND` according to JBoss documentation page.

What have I missed here? Is there anything that I have missed in my configuration?

Please note that, we have no choice other than exposing it under a context-path followed by the name (i.e. `/mycontext/access-management`). This is because of both our client requirements as well as the fact that we have many micro-services deployed under `/mycontext` each of which has its own ingress configuration.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess you need configure Keycloak `web-context` properly. E.g. `/mycontext/access-management/auth` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44624844/configure-reverse-proxy-for-keycloak-docker-with-custom-base-url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I managed to get this working by gathering all the solutions that are mentioned out there.

So basically, `web-context` needs to be set and that's something that is not mentioned anywhere in any documentation except word of mouth.

To set that, you can write a `cli` script:

```
set CONTEXT=${env.KEYCLOAK_WEB_CONTEXT}
echo $CONTEXT
embed-server --server-config=standalone-ha.xml --std-out=echo
/subsystem=keycloak-server/:write-attribute(name=web-context,value=$CONTEXT)
stop-embedded-server

embed-server --server-config=standalone.xml --std-out=echo
/subsystem=keycloak-server/:write-attribute(name=web-context,value=$CONTEXT)
stop-embedded-server
```

This is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46892613/keycloak-undertow-jboss-cli-set-web-context-from-environment-variable) but the important things are 1. you need to start embed server otherwise there is no server to connect to and second you should change both `standalone.xml` and `standalone-ha.xml` unless you know which one exactly you are running.

See this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58929616/988738) on how to copy custom scripts to your docker image.

**However, there is one important point here! Although Keycloak documentation says that you can change the front-end URL to whatever you want, you actually HAVE TO add `/auth` at the end of your new URL. It seems many pages in Keycloak are hardcoded to that path**

Now you need to set these two properties in your ConfigMap:

```
#ConfigMap
# Has to end with /auth and has to be absolute URL
KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL: https://your.website.address/mycontext/access-management/auth
PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
# The following is our own env var that will be used by the above cli
# Note that it SHOULD NOT start with / and it must END with /auth
KEYCLOAK_WEB_CONTEXT: mycontext/access-management/auth
```

This is a bit annoying because `KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL` cannot be relative path and has to be full absolute URL. The issue is you constructing that makes things not nice and elegant. Luckily we have a `host` property in `global` and is shared across the Helm's subcharts, so I could use it but really this makes the design a bit nasty.

But that's not just this, because of all these crap settings, now you have to change your `liveness` and `readiness` probes to `GET /mycontext/access-management`
And even worst, if you have micro-services, which is nearly 20 for us, you'll need to change all the auth server URLs that was previously as simple as `http://access-management:8080/auth` to `http://access-management:8080/mycontext/access-management/auth`.

Now make sure your ingress also includes this new path plus another important property `proxy-buffer-size`. If you don't have a large buffer size Keycloak requests may not work and you will get `Bad Gateway` error:

```
Path: /mycontext/access-management(/|$)(.*)
Rewrite To: /mycontext/access-management/$2
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: 8k
```

I really wished we could manage this with ingress without having to touch all these things but it seems not possible. I hope `Keycloak.X` will solve all these bad coding.

Comment: Wow. That is ridiculous. Thank you for this. I have been hitting my head against the wall for a few days trying to get Keycloak properly configured behind an ingress. The thing that did it for me was the webcontext. I am using the keycloak helm chart and ended up adding `initdbScripts` with some sed commands: `sed -i -e 's/<web-context>auth<\/web-context>/<web-context>keycloak\/auth<\/web-context>/' /opt/bitnami/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`, same for standalone-ha.xml

Answer (score 0):

`web-context` doesn't work in **Keycloak 18.x** anymore.

But you can use `http-relative-path` argument instead, which contains the path relative to '/'.

CLI: `--http-relative-path`

Env: `KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH`